# Inserting column into dataframe with multi-level index

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I've created a dataframe `data` which is a concatenation of various columns as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
data_lp = pd.read_csv("fil1.csv",sep=",", comment='#')
data_mip = pd.read_csv("file2.csv",sep=",", comment='#')
data=pd.concat([data_lp[['name','vars','con']],
                data_lp[['obj','t(ms)']],
                data_mip[['obj','t(ms)']]],
               keys=['','LP', 'MIP'],
               sort=False,axis=1)
```

Result:

```
                         LP                 MIP
    name    vars    con  obj        t(ms)   obj t(ms)
0   bop0    50      6    573.531624 155     285.0   252
1   bop1    50      6    420.036781 223     247.0   334
```

Now I would like to insert a new column `gap` under `MIP`, in between the columns `obj` and `t(ms)`. How can I do this?

```
gap=(data['LP']['obj']-data['MIP']['obj'])/data['MIP']['obj']
data['MIP'].insert(1,'gap',gap) #this doesn't work
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use tuple for assign value in `MultiIndex`, also is necessary change `1` to `6` for new sixth column:

```
data.insert(6,('MIP','gap'),gap)
print (data)
                          LP          MIP                
   name vars con         obj t(ms)    obj       gap t(ms)
0  bop0   50   6  573.531624   155  285.0  1.012392   252
1  bop1   50   6  420.036781   223  247.0  0.700554   334
```